# How to put vector in glue only in round brackets without "c"?

Tags: r, string

I have written a code:

```
my_values <- dbGetQuery(con, stri_encode(stores_query, to = "UTF-8")) %>%
  as.data.table()


table_query <- glue("
SELECT
  *
FROM MY_DB
WHERE 
  values IN {my_values} AND
LIMIT 100
")
```

The output is:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM MY_DB
WHERE 
  values IN c("john", "mike", "alex") AND
LIMIT 100
```

However I need this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM MY_DB
WHERE 
  values IN ('john', 'mike', 'alex') AND
LIMIT
```

As you see, I need to without vector sign "c", to make my query work. I also need values be in '', not in "". How to do it?

Comment: **Do not** use ‘glue’ to construct SQL strings! Doing so is a **massive security risk!** Only use SQL libraries with [prepared statements](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/lib/R/library/DBI/html/dbBind.html) (or use [`glue_sql`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html)).

Comment: What does `my_values` return?

Comment: @RonakShah vector with values c("john", "mike", "alex"). I need it to be in format ('john', 'mike', 'alex')

Comment: Can you update your post with `dput(my_values)`

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`glue_sql()`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_sql.html)**, and add `*` after the variable name placeholder inside `{…}`:

```r
table_query <- glue_sql("
SELECT
  *
FROM MY_DB
WHERE 
  values IN ({my_values*}) AND
LIMIT 100
", .con = con)
```

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM MY_DB
WHERE 
  values IN ('john', 'mike', 'alex') AND
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: it gives me ```SELECT
  *
FROM MY_DB
WHERE 
  values IN ('c("john", "mike", "alex")') AND
LIMIT 100```

Comment: @reredf No it doesn’t. It gives exactly what’s shown in my answer.

Comment: it does to me, though i did all the same. what can be reason?

Comment: Is `con` a valid database connection? What database system are you using?

Comment: Well that’s a bug. If you can make a reproducible example (preferably using an in-memory SQLite DB, i.e. `con = DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")` you could [submit it to the ‘glue’ issue tracker](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/new). However, before doing so please make sure that you’ve updated to the newest version of ‘glue’.